# Missing set-cookie header on POST method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-security, http-post, csrf

When i perform  a request using HTTP POST method from Angular, response comes without set-cookie header, contrary when I perform a request using HTTP GET method response comes with set-cookie Header.

I know that when POST method is used a preflight OPTIONS request is automatically issued by a browser. I am looking for advice what can i make so after POST method request client get set-cookie header as it already works with GET method?

My Angular request:

```
this.http.post<UserDto>("//localhost:8080/users", this.user, {withCredentials: true}).subscribe( user => {
  alert("User created successfully.");
});;
```

Those are response headers i get:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,PUT,DELETE,GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 05 May 2019 09:22:55 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

And my request headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
```

My Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        cors().and().
                csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and().addFilterBefore(
                new StatelessCSRFFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST","PUT","DELETE","GET","OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

I have found such an advice:

" I got it to work by adding a response filter for the pre-flight OPTIONS request that works without credentials.

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>No check for options</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All Access</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

I am not sure how to implement that solution is spring.

The CORS configuration has been set up correctly on the SpringFramework backend, as the methods succeed as expected, and Angular does set the cookies for GET requests. It is only POST operations that do not succeed if not preceded by HTTP.GET request.

Comment: Is it possible to filter in spring security pre-flight OPTIONS request?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add the response of your `GET` request, too. What kind of cookie do you set? Do you get the already added response for `OPTIONS` request or for `POST`request?